# What is the best tool for visualising hard drive usage on Windows Server 2008 (Web Edition)?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hard-drive, disk-space-utilization, cleanup

I've recently been tasked with cleaning up our Windows Server 2008 (Web Edition) server's website data folder.

There are over 50 sites hosted on this particular box, so I'm looking for an easy way to scan the the data folder, along each child folder to determine where the MB hogs are hiding.

On my development machine I use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/), but I'm not sure that this would be the best solution on a production server?

How would you go about it?

Comment: Thanks for the responses... I'll investigate all of the software and post a response on Monday, Japan time.

Comment: I'd just like to thank everyone for the responses. 

In the end I've gone with Treesize Free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Treesize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/products).

[image: Treesize Free Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [jam-software.com](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/screenshots/EN/freeware_treesize_kl.gif))</sub>

Comment: I still use an older version of Treesize pro that we bought that can be run w/out any install.

Answer (score 1):

I use [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) on my production SharePoint server (not to mention any other computer where I wonder what is eating up my hard drive space).  I love it and wouldn't use anything else.

Answer (score 1):

The old version of SpaceMonger ([this one](http://www.sixty-five.cc/sm/v1x.php)) is free, doesn't need to be installed and gives a nice graphical overview. But I don't know if it'll work on Windows Server 2008.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Sebastiaan

Answer (score 1):

I use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) file manager. Simply press Alt+Enter and you see dir sizes. It is very convenient for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Treesize (as mentioned in a comment above, we have an old version that we use because it can be run w/out any installation), we've used [Spacehound,](http://www.fineware.com/) but even though it has some nice features, I keep going back to Treesize.

I use Treesize to scan a whole drive and then when you're looking at all the directories sorted by size, it's easy to find any excessive uses - people who've duplicated folders, loaded up a ton of pictures or movies, whatever.